# Bluemix cf push error with manifest: expected services to be a list of strings

Tags: ibm-cloud, manifest, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to push an app to Bluemix on a Linux OS. However, the command line returns an error involving the manifest file:

```
Error reading manifest file:
Expected services to be a list of strings.
```

Here is the code for the manifest file:

```
applications:
- name: IdeaSocial
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  host: IdeaSocial
  domain: mybluemix.net
  path: .
  services:
   -SQL Database-v5
```

How do I fix this? Is there a form that the file needs to be in for the current version of Bluemix?

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes around `SQL Database-v5` to have it treated as a single string even though there is a space in it. Spaces matter in YAML.

```
  ...
  services:
  - "SQL Database-v5"
```

The [documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html) has more information and examples.